# Is there a way to show a downloaded file at the bottom when downloading through window.showSaveFilePicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, download, window

I want the user to be able to provide download location instead of having the file automatically downloaded to default location. I am able to do that but now user cannot see the file downloaded at the bottom of the browser which it used to show when getting downloaded automatically. I want to have advantages of both (to be able to choose download location and shown the file downloaded at the bottom).

This is currently the code i have right now.

```
 if ('showSaveFilePicker' in window) {
          window
            .showSaveFilePicker({ suggestedName: `${fileName}.mp4` })
            .then((fileHandle) => fileHandle.createWritable())
            .then((stream) => {
              stream.write(blob);
              stream.close();
            })
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            .catch((err) => console.log('SaveFile aborted'));
        } else {
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob]));
          const link = document.createElement('a');
          link.href = url;
          link.setAttribute('download', `${fileName}.mp4`);
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.click();
          link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently this seems impossible - [github issue](https://github.com/WICG/file-system-access/issues/379).

Note that when you use Save As for an image in Chrome, file picker appears and the download is shown in the browser and you can open it in the chosen folder from the browser. But this does not seem to work with the File System Access API right now.

Soo, I guess we will need to use some custom pop-up or notification that the download is in progress/completed. If anybody has made this work or has better ideas, please share!

Answer (score -1):

You can manually add/revoke the element like this:

```
if ('showSaveFilePicker' in window) {
  window
    .showSaveFilePicker({ suggestedName: `${fileName}.mp4` })
    .then((fileHandle) => fileHandle.createWritable())
    .then((stream) => {
      stream.write(blob);
      stream.close();
    })
    .then(() => {
      // Create a temporary URL and link to display the downloaded file at the bottom of the browser
      const tempUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const tempLink = document.createElement('a');
      tempLink.href = tempUrl;
      tempLink.setAttribute('download', `${fileName}.mp4`);
      document.body.appendChild(tempLink);
      tempLink.style.display = 'none';
      tempLink.click();
      setTimeout(() => {
        document.body.removeChild(tempLink);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(tempUrl);
      }, 100);
    })
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    .catch((err) => console.log('SaveFile aborted'));
} else {
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob]));
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute('download', `${fileName}.mp4`);
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this just does the download twice - once in the browser download directory and once in the file picker location.